# OpenERP OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.local'

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-8

I have a OpenERP from code (git repo) in my server in path /home/openerp/openerp and /home/openerp is home of openerp user, I'm using uwsgi and if I use:

```
uwsgi --ini myconf.ini --http 80
```

it's work but when I use supervisord for start uwsgi it has a error:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.local'
```

My uwsgi config is:

```
[uwsgi]
uid=openerp
gid=openerp
socket=/home/openerp/openerp.sock
chdir=/home/openerp/openerp
module=openerp-wsgi:application
master=True
workers=10
pidfile=/home/openerp/openerp.pid
vacuum=True
harakiri=50
max-request=5000
```

And mi config file of supervisord is:

```
[program:openerp]
command=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /home/openerp/openerp/uwsgi.ini
stopsignal=QUIT
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/openerp/err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/openerp/out.log
user=openerp
```

And all log error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/openerp/openerp/openerp-wsgi.py", line 15, in <module>
    import openerp
  File "./openerp/__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    import cli
  File "./openerp/cli/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from openerp.modules import module
  File "./openerp/modules/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import db, graph, loading, migration, module, registry
  File "./openerp/modules/loading.py", line 43, in <module>
    from openerp.modules.module import initialize_sys_path, \
  File "./openerp/modules/module.py", line 45, in <module>
    ad_paths = [tools.config.addons_data_dir]
  File "./openerp/tools/config.py", line 645, in addons_data_dir
    os.makedirs(d, 0700)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.local'
```

Answer (score 1):

I can fixed it writing in my uwsgi.ini:

```
env=XDG_DATA_HOME=/home/openerp/.local/share
```

But I don't understand why expand ~/.local/share to /.local/share